# How can I delete folders with a certain number of files?

Tags: windows-10

I Have a folder in Windows 10 that has a lot of subfolders in it. There are lots of files in them as well, however no more folders. There are some folders that only contain 2 or 3 files, so I was hoping for a way to delete folders with say 4 or less files. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Problem is telling it to only scan for certain directories within the one you want to wipe - ie. not wiping system32.

Comment: @Ramhound if you could point me towards one, that'd be great.
=

Comment: @Ramhound Then, Please do direct me to one.

Comment: Start here: [Powershell - List subdirectories and count files per subdirectory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26320770/3439404)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I wrote the script for you in vbs because I was bored at work. All you have to do is to create a new text file, copy-paste the script, replace the path in the last line to the path of the folder you want it to apply, save the text file with a .vbs extension.

```
Set fs = WScript.CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    set objFolder = fs.GetFolder(SubFolder)

        Set files = SubFolder.Files
        ShowSubFolders Subfolder
        if files.Count < 4 And objFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0 then
                fs.DeleteFolder Subfolder
        end if

    Next

end sub


ShowSubFolders fs.GetFolder("C:\your\folder\path\here")
```

PS: I did not spend too much time testing it, but it should be working. Just create a backup first and after running, compare it with the backup. I don't want you to loose any important files.

Comment: is something wrong with the script?

Comment: I'm Getting an Error with 
Line:5
Char:5
Error:Path not found
Code:800A004C

Comment: Got it. I had to remove the quotation marks and then it worked fine.

Comment: @SpencerNW - for me it worked with the quotation marks. It might be a change in Win10, don't know. Anyway take note what Ramhound wrote, this is not a code writing site, you need to learn at least the basics, start writing your code and if you can't solve something, just post it here, and someone will help getting it work. If I can help you with anything else, feel confident to ask.

Comment: @SpencerNW - If my answer solved the problem and you do not have any more questions, you can accept it as a solution.

Comment: Sorry about that, It slipped my mind.